# Protractor version 5.2.0 (Latest) - How to simulate keyboard key presses- TAB, ENTER?

Tags: protractor

Following NOT working:
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

```
it('validate the upload portfolio feature', function() {

    //loginPage.loginToPRA(); // not needed

    element(by.custLoc(ObjRep.validateUploadPortfolio.portUpload)).click();

    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
    browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

    browser.sleep(3000);
});
```

In Browse code button locator:

```
class="text-white background-teal cursor-pointer overflow-hidden padding-vertical-5 padding-horizontal-20 border-radius-4 border-shadow vertical-align-middle"
```

Comment: please put code , or anything to complete understand your problem

Comment: ++ Comments are Added!

Comment: protractor===window??, where is defined protractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two ways of Key-Inputs.

**Selenium Way: `browser.actions()`**

If you use `browser.actions().` you use the Selenium-Way and you must end it with `perform()` to execute the action.

Find [here in this Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) a short description plus a link to the detailed Selenium description with all possible key-actions.

**Protractor Feature `element.sendKeys()`:**

Here you actually don't need `browser.actions().`, but `element.`, because according to the [Protractor API description here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) `.sendKeys()` is a property/function followed after an `element`.

**So all described in Code** (I'm only using `element.sendKeys()`, so I didn't test the Selenium-Way)

```
//SELENIUM-ACTION SEQUENCE IN PROTRACTOR
//Press first TAB, execute it, then Enter, execute it. The current cursor position doesn't matter
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).perform();
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

//Press TAB then ENTER fast one after the other
browser.actions()
    .sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB)
    .sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER)
    .perform();

//PROTRACTOR
//focuses first the cursor to "element", then presses [TAB]
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);
//focuses first the cursor to "element", then presses [ENTER]
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
```

Comment: @AkshatRastogi : As it worked, please be so kind to mark the answer as "correct" (the checkmark left of it). It's the best way to say Thank You and it's part of the community's motivation, why we write answer.

Comment: While this is a fully correct answer that solves the user's problem, just to be 100% exact I'd like to point out that sendKeys() is in fact a function from Selenium Webdriver, independent of Protractor API.

Comment: Yes sir! I have upvoted the answer and marked your answer as "Correct".